Im trying to get a shadow free image using the technique given in the paper: https://www2.cs.sfu.ca/~mark/ftp/Pami06/pami06.pdf
Shadow Removal in Python OpenCV
With reference to the above link, im able to generate the 2d Invariant log image. Also as per the paper: https://www2.cs.sfu.ca/~mark/ftp/Pami06/pami06.pdf
i tried recovering the image as per the following code:
def remove_shadow(image, q_s, epsilon, num_iterations):
    shadow_free_channels = [remove_shadow_channel(image[:, :, i], q_s, epsilon, num_iterations) for i in range(3)]
    # Combine the shadow-free channels back into a color image
    shadow_free_image = np.stack(shadow_free_channels, axis=-1) * 255.0

    # Clip the pixel values to the valid range
    shadow_free_image = np.clip(shadow_free_image, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

    return shadow_free_image

import numpy as np
import cv2

def remove_shadow_channel(channel, q_s, epsilon, num_iterations):
    # Ensure channel is in floating point and add small value to avoid log(0)
    channel_log = np.log1p(channel.astype(np.float32))  
    # Compute gradients
    gradx = np.gradient(channel_log, axis=1)
    grady = np.gradient(channel_log, axis=0)
    # Initialize
    gradx_free = np.where(q_s, 0, gradx) 
    grady_free = np.where(q_s, 0, grady) 
    t = 0
    while t < num_iterations:
        gradx_temp = gradx_free.copy()
        grady_temp = grady_free.copy()
        for i in range(1, channel.shape[0] - 1):
            for j in range(1, channel.shape[1] - 1):
                gradx_temp = gradx_free.copy()
                grady_temp = grady_free.copy()
                if q_s[i, j]:
                    gradx_temp = gradx_free.copy()
                    grady_temp = grady_free.copy()
                    gradx_temp[i, j] = (gradx_free[i - 1, j] + gradx_free[i, j - 1] +
                                        gradx_free[i + 1, j] + gradx_free[i, j + 1])/4
                    grady_temp[i, j] = (grady_free[i - 1, j] + grady_free[i, j - 1] +
                                        grady_free[i + 1, j] + grady_free[i, j + 1])/4

        gradx_free = gradx_temp
        grady_free = grady_temp
        # Step 3: Fourier Transform for Integrability and Reconstruction
        M, N = channel.shape
        u = np.fft.fftfreq(N)
        v = np.fft.fftfreq(M)
        u, v = np.meshgrid(u, v)
      
        ax = np.exp(2j * np.pi * u)-1
        ay = np.exp(2j * np.pi * v)-1

        Fx = np.fft.fft2(gradx_free)
        Fy = np.fft.fft2(grady_free)

        denominator = np.abs(ax) ** 2 + np.abs(ay) ** 2
        denominator[0, 0] = 1
        Z = (np.conj(ax) * Fx + np.conj(ay) * Fy) / denominator
        Z[0, 0] = 0 

        shadow_free_channel_grad_logx = np.fft.ifft2(ax*Z).real
        shadow_free_channel_grad_logy = np.fft.ifft2(ay*Z).real
# Stopping Criteria
        if t > 0:
            diff = np.linalg.norm(shadow_free_channel_grad_logx - prev_shadow_free_channel_grad_logx) + \
                    np.linalg.norm(shadow_free_channel_grad_logy - prev_shadow_free_channel_grad_logy)
            if diff < epsilon:
                break

        prev_shadow_free_channel_grad_logx = shadow_free_channel_grad_logx
        prev_shadow_free_channel_grad_logy = shadow_free_channel_grad_logy
        t += 1

    # Convert back from logarithmic domain
    shadow_free_channel = np.fft.ifft2(Z).real 
    shadow_free_channel_exp = np.expm1(shadow_free_channel)
    return shadow_free_channel_exp


I'm able to generate 2d invariant chromaticity image mentioned in the paper along with the shadow edges. But using the above code im unable to obtain a shadow free image. Can anyone please help me in rectifying my mistake. Thank you
Need to know about the mistakes ive done in the code given
